# Calculate Column based on another column laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to calculate **amount** column based on **type** column. and display the result in **balance** column. with condition if debit is sum, and if credit is minus.
here is the table [calculate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yPh1.png)

I'm using laravel and this is the code in view

```
<thead>
    <tr class="txtcenter">
        <th class="all">Date </th>
        <th class="all">Description </th>
        <th class="all">Amount</th>
        <th class="all">Type</th>
        <th class="all">Reference</th>
        <th class="all">Balance</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>@foreach($get_period as $statement)
        <tr class="accordion">
            <td>{{SUBSTR($statement->created_at,0,10) }}</div>
            <td>{{$statement->desc }} </div>
            <td>IDR {{number_format($statement->amount, 0, '.', ',')}}  </div> 
            <td>{{ $statement->sign }}  </div>
            <td>{{ $statement->refdc }} </div>
            <td>  </div>
        </tr>@endforeach
</tbody>
```

I use this code in controller to calculate,

```
foreach($get_period as $statement)
        {
            $getsign = $statement->sign;
        }

        $balance = 0;
        if($getsign == "Debit"){
            foreach($get_period as $statement){
                $balance += $statement->amount;
            }       
        }else{
            foreach($get_period as $statement){
                $balance -= $statement->amount;
            }   
        }
```

but the result is always sum and display the final calculation like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDfpA.png)
..
I'm newbie in laravel and don't know what code to calculate this, maybe php or javascript or anything else. please help me.......
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a variable outside of loop of balance and deduct or add amount in that based on the value of type column. Here is how you can do it.

Take a balance variable out of the loop like this,

```
<?php $balance = 0; ?>
```

Now within loop perform the operation based on type value, like this,

```
<?php

if($statement->sign=="Debit") {
    $balance += $statement->amount;
} else {
   $balance -= $statement->amount;
}

?>
```

And keep displaying balance amount in each iteration like this,

```
{{ $balance }}
```

Comment: @arbong Yeah the code does that only, it calculates the balance amount as it iterates over the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why not working with [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators) . 
In your model class

```
public function getCalculatedBalanceAttribute($value)
{
    $balance = $this->balance - ($this->sign == 'Debit' ? -1 : 1) * $this->amount; 
    return $balance;
}
```

so your view would be like :

```
<tbody>@foreach($get_period as $statement)
        <tr class="accordion">
            <td>{{SUBSTR($statement->created_at,0,10) }}</div>
            <td>{{$statement->desc }} </div>
            <td>IDR {{number_format($statement->amount, 0, '.', ',')}}  </div> 
            <td>{{ $statement->sign }}  </div>
            <td>{{ $statement->refdc }} </div>
            <td>{{ $statement->calculated_balance }} </div>
        </tr>@endforeach
</tbody>
```